# How to analyze percent occurrence data (as counts or proportions)?

Tags: proportion, count-data

My example data:

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Summer", "Winter"), class = "factor"), 
    place = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
    ), class = "factor", .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), 
    count = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 0, 0), count_empty = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0), `% Empty` = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 
    0, 100, 60, 0, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have occurrence data with counts of fish catches ("count"), counts of those fish with empty stomachs ("count_empty"), and the proportion of fish caught with empty stomachs (count_empty/count = "%_Empty"). My question has two related parts:

1. If I want see if there are statistically significant differences between the place and time fish with empty stomachs are caught, would it make more sense to use the count data column or the proportion of fish with empty stomachs column as my data (and ignore the NA's/zero counts which make up 95% of my data)?
2. What analyses can I do with proportional data (GLM or wilcoxon)? Do I need to arcsine transform the proportion data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, data analysis based on counts should
use counts and not proportions or percentages. For example
8 Heads in 10 tosses of a coin is scant and unconvincing
evidence that the coin may be biased in favor of Heads.
By contrast, 79 Heads in 100 tosses is very strong evidence
of bias.

Your R code gives output as follows:

```
     time place count count_empty % Empty
1  Summer     A     0           0      NA
2  Summer     B     0           0      NA
3  Summer     C     0           0      NA
4  Summer     D     1           0       0
5  Summer     E     1           0       0
6  Winter     A     1           1     100
7  Winter     B     5           3      60
8  Winter     C     2           0       0
9  Winter     D     0           0      NA
10 Winter     E     0           0      NA
```

If this example is anywhere near a realistic representation
of the data you have, then you have too few catches in Summer for a reliable test.

In Winter, you have $1$ fish out of $1$ with an empty stomach
and $3$ fish out of $5$ with empty stomachs. You could
use such data in R with the procedure `prop.test` as follows:

```
prop.test(c(2,3), c(3,6))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(2, 3) out of c(3, 6)
X-squared = 3.328e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.6667933  1.0000000
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6666667 0.5000000 

Warning message:
In prop.test(c(2, 3), c(3, 6)) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

This test uses an approximation that may be invalid
because of low counts. Without the continuity correction,
the P-value is $0.6353 > 0.05 = 5\%,$ which would still
not be considered statistically significant.

Roughly equivalent is to test a $2 \times 2$ table
with rows for locations and columns for numbers with
empty stomachs.

```
TAB = cbind(c(1,1),c(2,6));  TAB
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    6
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TAB
X-squared = 5.576e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

In R, it is possible to simulate a P-value that may be more
useful. But for data in your example, the P-value does not
change.

Another thing to try for tables with low counts is Fisher's Exact Test, based on marginal totals of `TAB` and a hypergeometric distribution. Again, for your example, there is no significant evidence that winter feeding differs by location.

Even though your example shows no significant results, the
method for analyzing a table with larger counts should be
clear from the above.

If you have a lot more data in your actual study (for both summer and winter), then
you might try a chi-squared test on a $% \by 2 \by 2$ array, where
rows are for locations, columns are for counts of full and empty stomachs, and "slabs" are for summer and winter.

If you have trouble interpreting results from that chi-squared test, then you might post the three-way table (summer, then winter) in your question and ask for help with the interpretation.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is just an example dataset I made up because I didn't know how to share the real dataset. The real one has 8k rows of data and consists mostly of NA's with some low counts of fish (most common count is "1"). Thank you for your answer btw!